# Network controlled HDMI switch

Tags: hdmi, automation

Looking for an HDMI switch that has at least 4 inputs (1 output) and can be controlled/automated (preferably over Ethernet).

The budget is highly flexible so long as the minimum requirements are met. If a higher budget grants extra features, I'm all ears but anything over $200 likely has over-inflated margins and is not really what I'm interested in. So long as there is something (free or otherwise) to control the switch either automatically or with something that can be automated relatively cheaply, I'd be happy. Any form factor is fair game.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't necessarily the product I'd want but it's a low-end solution for **$18.28** USD: 
[image]

[http://www.amazon.com/EnjoyGadgets-Switcher-Selector-Support-Switching/dp/B003AQD5W6](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003AQD5W6)

Some IR sender could be programmed to control this. Perhaps something like this: [http://www.amazon.com/Global-Cache-IP2IR-iTach-Wired/dp/B003BFTKUC](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003BFTKUC) [+**$92.00** USD]

---

There's also a 5x1 option: [http://www.amazon.com/dp/B0049SCB2Y?psc=1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0049SCB2Y) for **$39.99** USD
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is one company that I have seen that makes a pretty good product for this - [Gefen's EXT-HD-MVSL-441](http://www.gefen.com/kvm/ext-hd-mvsl-441.jsp?prod_id=14882).

They have a multi-view switcher that takes 4 HDMI inputs and scales them, sizes them and outputs them either full screeen or in a "windowed" layout on a single HDMI montor.

Comment: Interesting product but **Price:** $1,999.00

Comment: I've been down the cheaper road and it always comes back to the same thing...you get what you pay for.  I needed this for a meeting room and the cheap ones just couldn't get the job done.  I probably spent that amount alone on the labor of installing diagnosing and reinstalling different solutions.

Comment: What didn't work exactly? I already have a fully functional "dumb" HDMI 3x1 switch that works perfectly for a variety of inputs. It was about $20.